# Relative import of custom python package fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a custom Python package with the following structure:

```
lisanode
|- __init__.py
|
|- compiler
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- graph.py
|  |- node.py
| 
|- toolbox
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- delays.py
\
```

Here's what I have in the various `__init__.py` files (the imported classes do exist in their respective modules):

```py
# lisanode/compiler/__init__.py
from .graph import Graph
```

```py
# lisanode/toolbox/__init__.py
from .delays import NestedDelays
```

```py
# lisanode/__init__.py
from .compiler import Graph
```

I install the package locally using pip3: `pip3 install -e .`.

This works very well when I execute the command-line tools defined in my package (as an entry-point) from the lisanode directory. However, I get an error when I try to run the same command-line from outside the project's directory:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/lisanode", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('lisanode', 'console_scripts', 'lisanode')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lisanode/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .compiler import Graph
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lisanode.compiler'
```

Do you know why that is?

Comment: Sorry, you're right: I tried to modify lisanode/__init__.py to point directly to the module, but it didn't work either. I edited the question with the error message that I get using the described structure.

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue with the structure shown. Can you import the ``lisanode`` package in a ``python3`` shell?

Comment: Nope, I get the same error… Funny thing is that it works on some computers and does not on some others running the same version of Python. I must be missing something here!